# Can't append JSON value into modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, append

I have some divs that each contain a Category and clicking on a specific div opens a modal for that Category. There's data coming in via axios and I'm trying to append the Description of each Category into their respective modals.

I'm able to see the Descriptions in the console but for some reason I'm having a tough time appending them into their modals.

Screencap of **[`console.log(desc)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i98p1.png)**

#### JS snippet:

```
axios.get([redacted] + "/getByTitle('Categories')/items?$select=Title,Description,Courses/Title,SortOrder&$expand=Courses&$orderby=Title&$top=1000",
   {
       method: "GET",
       credentials: "include",
       mode: "no-cors",
       headers: {
           "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
   }
 // irrelevant code
   ]).then(axios.spread((cat, lib) => {
        _categories = cat.data.d.results;
        _library = lib.data.d.results;

        this.loadCourses();
   })).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
   });

getPayload(){
    return _library;
}

getCategories(){ 
    return _categories;
}

loadCourses(){ // Training Library
    let crs = _library
       .map(x => {
           return {
                "Description": x.Description,
                "Title": x.Title
           }
       }).sort();

   this.populateCategory(crs, "div.top-training");
}

populateCategory(arrObj, parentTarget){
        arrObj = arrObj.filter((v, p) => arrObj.indexOf(v) == p);

        $.each(arrObj, function(idx, val) {

            let targetDiv = $(parentTarget).hasClass(".cat-box");
            let desc = _categories
                 .filter(x => {
                   return x.Description 
                 });

           console.log(desc)

            let modalTrigger = $('<div />', {
                'class': '.cat-box',
                'data-category': val.Category,
                'data-target': '#modal-id',
                'data-toggle': 'modal',
                'text': val
            });

       modalTrigger.prepend("<span class='mag-glass'>&#128269;</span>");
       modalTrigger.append("<span style='display:none;'>" + (desc?desc:"") + "</span>");

         targetDiv.append(modalTrigger);
  });
```

#### index.js:

```
import AllCoursesComponent from './SiteAssets/scripts/allCourses';

let allComp = new AllCoursesComponent();

$(document).on("click", '.cat-box', function(val) {
    console.log('.cat-box clicked')

let cat  = $(this).data('category')
    desc = $(this).find("p").last().text();
    // console.log('desc: ' + desc)

    $(".category-desc").empty();

    $(".category-desc").append(desc + "<br />");

// irrelevant code

});
```

#### Modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-id" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-backdrop">
          <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-img"></div>

            <div class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></div>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="category-desc">
                  <p></p>
              </div>
              <div class="training-titles">
                <ul class="training-titles-ul"></ul>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div> <!-- modal-content -->
        </div> <!-- modal-backdrop -->

    </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Where it the snippet has `.then(axios.spread((cat, lib) => {
        _categories = cat.data.d.results;` Does the `.data` contain JSON that needs to be parsed? `JSON.parse(cat.data).d.results`

Comment: Hey @Robofan, from what I know it's already been parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

In my project I appended the Category Titles into the Category divs a specific way---I left it out of this question because it didn't seem relevant, but I tried repeating the process with the Category Description and it ended up working:

```
         let catBoxElems = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) { // creates divs based on how many categories are present
            // the initial category div is cloned:
                catBoxElems += 
                "<div class='cat-box cat-num-" + i + "'data-target='#modal-id' data-toggle='modal' data-desc='" + categs[i].Description + "'data-title='" + categs[i].Title + "'>" + catPic + "<br>" + categs[i].Title + "</div>";
            }

            $(document).find("#modal-id").off("shown.bs.modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
                $(document).find(".modal-title").html($(e.relatedTarget).data("title"));
                $(document).find(".category-desc").html($(e.relatedTarget).data("desc"));
            }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {
                $(document).find(".modal-title").html("");
            });
```

I didn't really consider it before because I wasn't sure it was going to work. So now clicking on the Animals category, for instance, opens the modal and the Animals description shows up. Clicking on a different category opens the modal and shows that category's description.